# how to fix IDA pro call analysis failed error?

Tags: c++, disassembly

this is the source code of the program
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjhyp.png

and this is ida pro throwing the error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmK1f.png

note: I'm trying to de compile the big square

Comment: Suggest https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ where plenty of IDA experts including the author himself can be found.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)